# Can every category be equipped with a monoidal structure?

Tags: category-theory, monoidal-categories

By definition, a [monoidal category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoidal_category) is a category $\mathbf{C}$ equipped with a bifunctor

$$
\otimes :\mathbf{C} \times \mathbf{C} \rightarrow \mathbf{C}
$$

and an object $I$ that is both a left and right identity for $\otimes$, that satisfies some associative conditions.

The question is, for any category $\mathbf{C}$, is it always possible to find a bifunctor $\otimes$ that renders it into a monoidal one?

If not, what is a minimal counterexample to convince a layman? Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As a consequence of the [Eckmann-Hilton argument](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Eckmann-Hilton+argument), the endomorphism monoid of the unit object in a monoidal category is always commutative.  (Besides the usual composition monoid structure, it also has a monoid structure coming from the canonical isomorphism $1\otimes 1\to 1$ which you can check is compatible with the composition operation such that the Eckmann-Hilton argument applies.)  So, if a category has no object whose endomorphism monoid is commutative, it does not admit a monoidal structure.  This of course includes the empty category, but also includes, for instance, the category of sets with more than one element.

Comment: Thanks! So a minimal nontrivial counterexample would be a category with a single object x, and two morphisms f,g:x->x such that fg≠gf. Is this interpretation of your answer correct?

Comment: That would work, yes.

Comment: Though it still confuses my naïve mind. Suppose we define a bifunctor such that $x\otimes x=x$, and treat x as identity $I$, without invoking the E-H argument, what definition or condition of monoidal category is violated in this case?

Comment: Functoriality of $\otimes$ would mean that $(f_1\otimes g_1)\circ(f_2\otimes g_2)=(f_1\circ f_2)\otimes(g_1\circ g_2)$ and while naturality of $x\otimes x\cong x$ (from the unit axioms) would require that $f\otimes\mathrm{id}_x=f=\mathrm{id}_x\otimes f$. These are the hypothesis of the Eckmann-Hilton argument; its conclusion is that $f\otimes g=f\circ g=g\circ f=g\otimes f$. So either functoriality or naturality of the unitors would be violated, and I'd say it's the naturality of the unitors.

Answer (score 5):

Not every category can be equipped with a monoidal structure: the empty category is not monoidal, since there is no object that can be chosen for the unit.

Every discrete nonempty category (i.e. nonempty set) [can be equipped with (commutative) monoidal structure](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/455619).

Comment: I don't think this construction works:  if $X$ is the unit, then you need to specify unitor isomorphisms $X \otimes Y \simeq Y \simeq Y \otimes X$ for all objects $Y$, and these will not exist when $Y$ is not isomorphic to $X$.

Comment: @RaviFernando: whoops, thanks!