# Can every (co)complete (in some sense) category be equipped with a monoidal structure?

Tags: category-theory, monoidal-categories

Follow up to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4489476/1047318). Here the answers use the fact that not every category has an object whose
endomorphism monoid is commutative. This can be fixed by for example only considering categories with initial or terminal objects. Is there some (co)completeness property that guarantees that a category can be equipped with monoidal structure?

Comment: Not a full answer to your question, but it looks like you're interested in semi-cartesian monoidal categories (https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2016/08/monoidal_categories_with_proje.html), since a monoidal category whose unit is the terminal object is the same as a monoidal category with projection maps $\pi_1: X \otimes Y \rightarrow X$ and $\pi_2: X \otimes Y \rightarrow Y$. The research about when those projections can exist would seem to be what you're looking, though I'd be surprised if there's a complete categorisation out there.

Comment: @EzioGreggio: That should be an answer!

Answer (score 2):

A category with binary products and terminal object $1$ is (not strictly) monoidal, because $A\times (B\times C)\cong (A\times B)\times C$, naturally in $A,B,C$, and $1×A\cong A\cong A×1$, naturally in $A$. Such monoidal structure is called *cartesian*, and dually, a category with coproducts and initial object has a *cocartesian* monoidal structure.

Comment: Oh i totally forgot that, i should have asked about whether ever category with a initial (or with a terminal) object can be equipped with monoidal structure instead.